# List repeating at the end / carousel-like

Tags: flutter

I have a list of small icons and want to repeat the icons when the end of the list is reached (as a carousel with about > 8 items on the screen simultaniously) where the user can select elements to display different content.

Is there some widget available for that case?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### `PageView`

You can use a [`PageView`](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/PageView-class.html) for this, i.e. specifically [`PageView.builder`](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/PageView/PageView.builder.html).

You would use modulo to loop your items when the end of your pages is reached:

```dart
PageView.builder(
  itemBuilder: (context, index) => Icon(icons[index % 8]),
  // ...
)
```

In this example, you would have `8` icons that are returned to the builder and once the user scrolls the the ninth item in your list, the first icon is shown again and so on.

#### `ListView`

You can do the same with a [`ListView`](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/ListView-class.html) if you prefer the behavior, i.e. specifically with [`ListView.builder`](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/ListView/ListView.builder.html):

```dart
ListView.builder(
  itemBuilder: (context, index) => Icon(icons[index % 8]),
  // ...
)
```

Comment: Thanks - but what I want is to have a list, where you see more than one item on the screen - something like:
<br/>
[1] [2] [3] [4] [5]
<br/>
and when scolling

[2] [3] [4] [5] [6]
and repeating like
[7] [8] [1] [2] [3]

the amount of visible items should depend on the space - so it should look like a list...

so

ListView.builder(
  itemBuilder: (context, index) => Icon(icons[index % 8]),
  // ...
)

is working for me :-)

Comment: @derChris I can understand that and will add `ListView.builder` to the answer since it is analogous.